# angular convert string array to json object array

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a textarea field in my form

```
   <ion-item>
     <ion-label>Attributes and operations*</ion-label>
     <ion-textarea formControlName="responsibilities"></ion-textarea>
   </ion-item>
```

When I submit the form I get following form value:

```
{"thing":"Book","responsibilities":"Name ISBN","collaborators":""}
```

The submit function:

```
createCard(formData){

    this.responsibilities = this.addCRCCardForm.value.responsibilities.split(" ");
    console.log(this.responsibilities)

    for (let res of this.responsibilities){
        //test
    }
}
```

The console statement prints: `["Name", "ISBN"]`

I want instead my form value to be (to send to my backend):

```
{"thing":"Book","responsibilities": [{name: "Name"},{name: "ISBN"}],"collaborators":[{..},{..}]
```

Where and what I have to modify?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of any form object. You can call

```
This.addcrccardform.get ('responsibilities')
```

Which will return an AbstractControl that can be cast into its actual type such as formgroup or formarray (for typed purposes)

Getting the .value of that object will display the controls of responsibilities in object form or you can loop through the .controls of the object and do what you need to do.

You can .get on any form object to get the AbstractControl which should give you all the functionality you need.

This is all of course assuming youre using Angulars reactive forms.

It may be helpful to create an object for submission purposes and set up a class in the format the server needs. Then push the subcontrols as values into their respective arrays

Hope this helps